# Next.js middleware Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, next.js, firebase-admin

Getting this error in Next.js `_middleware` file when I try to initialize Firebase admin V9. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:22:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

`../../firebase/auth-admin`

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY,
    }),
  });
}

const firestore = admin.firestore();

const auth = admin.auth();

export { firestore, auth };
```

Calling it in my `_middleware`

```
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { auth } from "../../firebase/auth-admin";

export default async function authenticate(
  req: NextRequest,
  ev: NextFetchEvent
) {
  const token = req.headers.get("token");
  console.log("auth = ", auth);
  //   const decodeToken = await auth.verifyIdToken(token);
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

I saw a solution [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/150#issuecomment-488780989) by customizing webpack but this does not fix it.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { isServer, node }) => {
    node = {
      ...node,
      fs: "empty",
      child_process: "empty",
      net: "empty",
      tls: "empty",
    };
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Edge Runtime, which is used by Next.js Middleware, does not support Node.js native APIs.

From the [Edge Runtime](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime#unsupported-apis) documentation:

> The Edge Runtime has some restrictions including:
>
> - Native Node.js APIs **are not supported**. For example, you can't read or write to the filesystem
> - Node Modules *can* be used, as long as they implement ES Modules and do not use any native Node.js APIs

You can't use Node.js libraries that use `fs` in Next.js Middleware. Try using a client-side library instead.

Comment: Dec 2022: I tried using the client-side library instead (to get a document from firestore), using the v9 tree-shakeable firebase lib. It didn't really work: some requests would succeed, most would fail with "Network connection lost" from the edge function. During build, I see ```./node_modules/@firebase/installations/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js
A Node.js API is used (BroadcastChannel at line: 373) which is not supported in the Edge Runtime.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime```

so I don't think this approach works. The request was 300 ms which was too long anyway

Comment: @xaphod It doesn't look like the Edge Runtime supports `BroadcastChannel` either. Check https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime for all the supported Web APIs.

Comment: well yeah, that was the point of my comment -- that there currently doesn't appear to be a firebase client-side library you can safely use on the Edge Runtime, at least to access Firestore. I think it's a bad idea to be making network calls from the edge like this though in any case? Not sure...

Answer (score 4):

I wasted a lot of time tying to get this to work. The weird thing is that this will work in the api itself.

So instead of calling firebase-admin action in the `_middleware` file. Call it in the api itself like:

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { auth } from "../../firebase/auth-admin";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const authorization = req.headers.authorization
  console.log(`Handler auth header: ${authorization}`)

  if (!authorization) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authorisation header not found.' })
  }

  const token = authorization.split(' ')[1]
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Bearer token not found.' })
  }

  console.log(`Token: ${token}`)

  try {
    const {uid} = await auth.verifyIdToken("sd" + token)
    console.log(`User uid: ${uid}`)
    res.status(200).json({ userId: uid })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`verifyIdToken error: ${error}`)
    res.status(401).json({ message: `Error while verifying token. Error: ${error}` })
  }
}
```

A workaround to make this reusable is to create a wrapper function.

If anyone knows how to make this work in a `_middleware` file, I would be really grateful.

Edit: Gist for the wrapper middleware function:
https://gist.github.com/jvgrootveld/ed1863f0beddc1cc2bf2d3593dedb6da

Comment: Half decent solution, still not automatically hooked into the routes, though. Seems the only way to do that at the moment would be a custom server which would prevent hosting on Vercel. Honestly I've found Next middleware to be a nightmare to work with. Not being able to make custom network requests (not using `fetch`) removes so much flexibility. How are people checking API keys against backend stores with middleware? I don't get how Next doesn't support this, very common use case for many APIs.

Comment: +1 lol. Nextjs middleware is still a pain to work with. Best solution I found was to decode and verify tokens (or API keys) in each route, rather than doing it in middleware.  The killer was realizing I couldn't decode tokens at the middleware with jsonwebtoken... So it peppers a fair bit of boilerplate, but does solve the problem. Nextjs middleware has greatly improved over the last few months though.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're not calling firebase-admin in the client

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently released a library that aims to solve the problem: https://github.com/ensite-in/next-firebase-auth-edge

It allows to create and verify tokens inside Next.js middleware and Next.js 13 server components. Built entirely upon Web Crypto API.

Please note it does rely on Next.js ^13.0.5 experimental "appDir" and "allowMiddlewareResponseBody" features.